# How to use Reactive Extensions for an event bus

Tags: c#, linq, system.reactive

I'm having a hard time trying to figure out how to use reactive extensions to create an event bus in C# without the Subject class which I understand is is not recommended.

Most of the IEvents are my own but some like mouse & keyboard events will supplied by WPF.

I prefer the idea of posting events to the Event Bus rather that using event handlers everywhere with Observable.FromEventPattern as some of these events will sometimes be logged only by subscribers and not acted on.

Heres a snippet showing what I am trying to do.

```
 public interface IEvent { } // marker interface

 public class BarcodeReaderEvent : EventArgs, IEvent
 { }

 public class MouseEvent : EventArgs, IEvent
 { }

 public class MyEventBus
 {
     private static IObservable<IEvent> eventBus = ??

     public void Post<IEvent>(IEvent theEvent)
     {
       // What goes here? 
     }

     public IDisposable Subscribe()
     {
         return ??
     }
 }
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If you were to want to use the structure that you've put forward you would need to use a subject.

Your code would basically look like this:

```
public interface IEvent { }

public class BarcodeReaderEvent : EventArgs, IEvent { }

public class MouseEvent : EventArgs, IEvent { }

public class MyEventBus
{
    private Subject<IEvent> _subject = new Subject<IEvent>();
    private IObservable<IEvent> _eventBus;

    public MyEventBus()
    {
        _eventBus = _subject.AsObservable();
    }

    public void Post(IEvent theEvent)
    {
        _subject.OnNext(theEvent);
    }

    public IDisposable Subscribe(IObserver<IEvent> observer)
    {
        return _eventBus.Subscribe(observer);
     }
}
```

However, the problem with subjects is that if there is an error on the subject then every single subscription to the subject will receive an `OnError` notification and all of the subscriptions would then end.

Your code did have a few "weirdnesses" in it too. Your `private static IObservable<IEvent> eventBus` was `static`, but the class wasn't. I don't know if that was intended or not. Also the `public void Post<IEvent>(IEvent theEvent)` seemed to imply that you wanted to pass in `IEvent` as a generic type (meaning that you're shadowing the actual interface type with the generic type). It's possible that you meant `public void Post<T>(T theEvent) where T : IEvent`, but I couldn't tell.

You could try this, which I think is closer to what you actually want, and see if it suits you better:

```
public class MyEventBus
{
    private Subject<IEvent> _subject = new Subject<IEvent>();

    public void Post<T>(T message) where T : IEvent
    {
        _subject.OnNext(message);
    }

    public IObservable<T> AsObservable<T>() where T : IEvent
    {
        return _subject.OfType<T>();
    }
}
```

Alternatively, you may want to look at this example of a more complex event bus using Rx: https://github.com/reactiveui/ReactiveUI/blob/main/src/ReactiveUI/Routing/MessageBus.cs

Comment: The link you posted at the end has disappeared. I can't seem to find the MessageBus class in the System.Reactive assembly.

Answer (score 5):

The use of subject is only as not-recommended as the use of an Event Bus. If you are deciding to have a single point to which everyone publishes and listens to, then may as well go all in and use a subject too.

As suggested in other posts, the standard recommendation is to have dedicated resources/services that expose domain specific events. Instead of a having a general Event Bus/Event Aggregator (anti-pattern IMO) where every client must filter out for message that they hope are being published. They should just subscribe to dedicated endpoints.

Comment: Subscribers would only receive relevant filtered events. Your Into RX website is very helpful. Thanks.

Comment: Hi, you say "As suggested in other posts". Could you refer me to some of these posts, as I'm currently designing an application and would like to avoid the Event Bus anti-pattern, but am trying to learn about good alternatives. Thanks! Love your Rx material!